# Explain for(var cat in livingCats) syntax?

Tags: javascript, syntax

```
livingCats = {"bob": true, "bo": false};
for(var cat in livingCats)
  print(cat);
```

This outputs all of  the names in the object whether it is true or not. 
I do not remember defining cat as anything in the object, so why can we use cat to print each name?
Can cat be exchanged for anything and it does not matter?

More info please on the syntax of using a var and in to print the keys.

from the answers and from reading more into the documentation that the cat variable was not defined but is an enumerable, thus can be used in for..in. Cat can be replaced by anything.

Comment: Yes, `cat` can be anything and it's only a variable. [Check MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

Comment: http://www.ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_12.htm#Section_12.6.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn’t define `cat` as anything *in the object*. You defined it as a variable, and did so *within the `for` statement*.

This makes JavaScript assign each property name of the `livingCats` object to `cat` in turn, and runs the code inside your `for` statement each time. It doesn’t look at the value of the property, it just assigns the property name to `cat`.

Your particular `for` loop is equivalent to this code:

```
print("bob");
print("bo");
```

Although note that once the loop has ended, `cat` will still have the last value assigned to it in the loop.

Comment: Equivalent in JavaScript implementations that preserve the order of properties, that is.

Comment: which is ... all, even if not enforced by spec

Comment: @user1737909: oh really? Cool.

Comment: @user1737909: Well, a quick test shows that ActionScript (also a derivative of ECMAScript) doesn't preserve the order. I wouldn't assume so quickly that all JavaScript implementations enumerate properties in the order they were added; only the *browser* JavaScript specification specifies that.

Comment: yeah, sorry, I don't count crap amongst JS implementations (not sorry for trolling tho :p). (note that was I said isn't true for numerical keys). EDIT : Oh, looks like you're everywhere, @PaulD.Waite

Answer (score 0):

The variable in `for()` can be anything, it's just to represent the generic keys in the object.